What Victoreen is in "Victoreen high-resistance types"?


Figure 1.2. A selection of common resistor types. Top row, left to right (wirewound ceramic power resistors): 20W vitreous enamel with
leads, 20W with mounting studs, 30W vitreous enamel, 5W and 20W with mounting studs. Middle row (wirewound power resistors): 1W,
3W, and 5W axial ceramic; 5W, 10W, 25W, and 50W conduction-cooled (“Dale-type”). Bottom row: 2W, 1W, 1/2
W, 1/4
W, and 1/8
W carbon
composition; surface-mount thick-film (2010, 1206, 0805, 0603, and 0402 sizes); surface-mount resistor array; 6-, 8-, and 10-pin single
in-line package arrays; dual in-line package array. The resistor at bottom is the ubiquitous RN55D 1/4
W, 1% metal-film type; and the pair
of resistors above are Victoreen high-resistance types (glass, 2GΩ; ceramic, 5GΩ).
The Art of Electronics, 3rd edition

At the last line of above paragraph, what Victoreen is in Victoreen high-resistance types?
I see surface of resistor in above picture write with Victoreen.
Does Victoreen refer to name of a person who named John Austin Victoreen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Austin_Victoreen)?

Victoreen Instrument Company was a U.S. based manufacturer, and it was named after John Austin (Jack) Victoreen.
The high value/high voltage resistors were developed for some of their instrumentation.

Critical to the instrument work was the development of high
resistance resistors with magnitudes of \$10^{14} \text{ to }
> 10^{15}\$ Ohms. These resistors required a technique development to
put graphite on glass. Dr. Victoreen has noted that the code names
were classified but the designs were not since many had been developed
before the Manhattan Project. The contract between Victoreen and the
Manhattan Project was secret, however, it should be noted that
Victoreen made significant contributions to the Manhattan Projects
success.

